# How to return data from callback of mongoose query function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

It's my first ever project with mongodb and I'm developing an URL shortener using `express` and `mongoose`. I'm having problem with returning data from callback function.

I've two schemas as follow:

```js
//Store the url, corresponding short url and number of clicks.
const urlSchema = new Schema({
  url: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  short: {
    type: Number,
    require: true,
    unique: true
  },
  clicks: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    default: 0
  }
});

//Stores the number of documents in URL Schema.
const urlCounter = new Schema({
  count: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1
  }
});
```

And the handler function to save documents

```js
//Count and increment the number of documents in URLSchema
const incrementCounter = (callback) => {
  URLCounter.findOneAndUpdate({}, { $inc: {count: 1 } }, (err, counter) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    if (counter) {
      callback(counter.count);
    }
    else {
      const newCounter = new URLCounter();
      newCounter.save((err, counter) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        URLCounter.findOneAndUpdate({}, { $inc: {count: 1 } }, (err, counter) => {
          if (err) return console.error(err);
          callback(counter.count);
        });
      });
    }
  });
}

const shortenURL = (url) => {
  if (!verifyURL(url)) {
    return {error: "invalid URL"};
  }
  //first check if the url is already shortened and stored
  return URLSchema.findOne({url: url}, (err, storedURL) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    if (storedURL) {
      //if URL is already shortened and stored
      return { original_url: storedURL.url, short_url: storedURL.short };
    }
    else {
      //if URL isn't already shortened and stored
      incrementCounter((count) => {
        const newURL = new URLSchema({
          url: url,
          short: count
        });
        newURL.save((err) => {
          if (err) return console.error(err);
          return { original_url: url, short_url: count };
        });
      });
    }
  });
}
```

[Code on Github](https://github.com/i-anshuman/url-shortener-microservice)

The problem is in the function `shortenURL`. I'm trying to return the `JS objects` inside the `if-else` block, but it return the result of `URLSchema.findOne`.
How to return `objects` the from `if-else` block?? Please help me!!
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

I would just remove the 'return' from URLSchema.findOne({}) since you are already returning json objects inside the function. To improve further, I would return the errors in json form for ease of handling errors.

```
const shortenURL = (url) => {
  if (!verifyURL(url)) {   //first check if the url is already shortened and stored
    console.log('INVALID URL!!!')
    return { error: "invalid URL" };
  }
  else {
    URLSchema.findOne({ url: url }, (err, storedURL) => { // removed return 
      if (err) {
          console.log('URLSchema.findOne() error:', err)
          return {error: err}; // returns error in json
      }
      if (storedURL) {
        //if URL is already shortened and stored
        console.log('StoredURL url', storedURL.url)
        console.log('StoredURL short', storedURL.short)
        return { original_url: storedURL.url, short_url: storedURL.short };
      }
      else {
        //if URL isn't already shortened and stored
        console.log('URL IS NOT SHORTEN AT ALLLLL!')
        incrementCounter((count) => {
          const newURL = new URLSchema({
            url: url,
            short: count
          });
          newURL.save((err) => {
            if (err) 
                console.log('newURL.save() error:', err)
                return {error: err}; // returns error in json
            }
            console.log('Returning og url', url)
            console.log('Returning count', count)
            return { original_url: url, short_url: count };
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm may I know what are you getting back this time? I want to know what is happening inside the callback function so I updated my answer. Could you run it and tell me what was printed?